# References and Bibliography in two distinct chapters of Quarto book

Tags: lua, pandoc, quarto

I would like to put References and Bibliography in two distinct chapters of the book. The "References" are the things actually cited in the text, but the "Bibliography" is just a manually created chapter before or after the References chapter.

So, i would like to write a chapter file `bib.qmd` like:

```
# The bibliography

@source1
@source2
@source3
... etc
```

However, i haven't found a way to obtain the full content using cites, i only get author or number depending on the CSL. Obviously i could write all that content by hand, but i prefer to do it through the corresponding citation.

I have read about [including uncited items](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/footnotes-and-citations.html#including-uncited-items), and sound like what i want but i need them in a different chapter and not merged within the references.

Im thinking to write a lua filter to run after quarto's citeproc, and somehow reuse the output of citeproc but not sure if this is a viable path.

Comment: So you want to keep the uncited reference in the `bib.qmd` file?

Comment: @shafee Yes. More in general, i would like to full cite something that is listed in the references.bib file whenever i want, independently if it was cited or not somewhere.

Comment: Are you open to latex based solution?

Comment: Do you mean a solution only for latex output?. I'm looking for an html and pdf solution.

Answer (score 0):

The idea to use a Lua filter is a good one. The biggest challenge is to collect all uncited items. You'd first get the full list of available items with the `pandoc.utils.references` function, collect all used keys by filtering on all `Cite` keys, and then use `pandoc.utils.citeproc` to generate and process a document with the uncited references.

If you have all uncited items in a single `.bib` file then you could use a pre-existing filter like [multibib](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/multibib). Otherwise you might be able to adapt that filter to fit your requirements.

Comment: I think this could be helpful. Im testing multibib, however im trying the example of the documentation and doesnt work. Metadata `bibliography: main: main-bibliography.bib etc` returns: Field "bibliography" has value
main: main-bibliography.bib
  software: software.bib

The value must instead be a string.

Comment: Even the R studio editor complains that `bibliography: main: main-bibliography.bib ...` must be a string.

Comment: BTW, im on quarto v1.2.280, pandoc v2.19.2